# How do we get $S(m) = S(m/2) + \lg m$ from $T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \lg\lg n$?

Tags: recurrence-relations, logarithms

I am confused about example we got today in class.
Here is a recurrence and I am not sure how we got

$S(m)=S(m/2)+(\lg m)$

$$T(n)=T(\sqrt{n}) + (\lg\lg n) $$ Let  $$m =\lg n$$
$$S(m)=S(m/2)+(\lg m) $$

Case2 of MT $$ ((\lg\lg n)^2)$$

How did we get m/2 ?
$2^m = n$   and $\sqrt{2^m} = 2^{m/2}$ not $m/2$

Also why is it Case 2?

Comment: $$m=\lg n\implies \lg\sqrt n=m/2$$

Comment: @Did can you explain... I am not strong in math and its confusing for me :(